# execute bash script from java

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to execute a bash script file , for a java program it the following way :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./path/to/bash");
```

But it seems to be not the correct way for doing it because it return the following exception:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./path/to/bash": error=2, No such file or directory
```

what is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Can you check that your bash file is in the correct path relatively? You may try to change the path to an absolute one and then check it.

Comment: if the program is in the expected path, make sure that all pathes inside of the bash file are correct and all programs are in path

Comment: the path of my bash file is correct yes

Comment: @sali333 please checkout the latest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I used the below approach to execute a bash script.

```
 Process exec = getRuntime().exec("/home/user/test/test.sh");
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(exec.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
        System.out.println(s.next());
```

Whenever I tried `getRuntime().exec("./home/user/test/test");` I got the exact error you were getting. `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./home/user/test/test": error=2, No such file or directory`. 
To execute any command from any directory, please follow the below approach.

```
String []command ={"/bin/bash","-c", "ls"};
Process exec = getRuntime().exec(command,null,new 
     File("/home/user/test"));
java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(exec.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
System.out.println(s.next());
```

Hope this is some way helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./path/to/bash": error=2, No such file or direct
```

It mean path of file was wrong.
Please check file path again.
What folder contains this file?

Comment: The file is in my desktop

Comment: If you are using Window. In order to execute bash file, you need input full of path
Ex: C:/Users/path/to/bash

Comment: I m using linux

Comment: Please change code to


    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "/home/username/Desktop/bash"});

Answer (score 1):

To execute any bash command using java , you can use command like  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path-to/bash -c \"rm *.foo\"")` - This will remove all the files having extension `.foo` in the current working directory